# Retrieve private repository commits from github

Tags: django, git, github, github-api

I need to retrieve all commits from Private repositories on github.

I already tried with with github API documentation. It provides the API for retrieving the public repository commits.
  https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits

Anybody can help me for taking all commits from private repositories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A private repository means you need to authenticate in order to execute your query (here getting the commits).
This should work, if you own the private repo:

```
curl -u 'username:password' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

Comment: How do you extend this to 2-factor auth?

Comment: @Feras Well... First, two-factor auth was not in place for GitHub at the time of my answer (Nov. 2012 vs. Sept 2013: https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication) ;) Second, you need an X-GitHub-OTP header: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27747524/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/20065691/6309

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `Personal access tokens` for specific use... [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

[image]

using postman:

`https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits`
[image]