# Github API access to private repos using OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, github, github-api

Trying to access files in the private repositories of a Github organization of which I am a member, using the API. Tried a couple different ways so far:

**1.** If I use the [username/password method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277286/retrieve-private-repository-commits-from-github?rq=1) --

```
curl -u "sashafklein:mypassword" https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/git/trees/:file_sha
```

it works fine, but I'm trying to access the repos from a collaborative Rails app, so I don't want to publicize my github login credentials. I suppose creating a dummy GH account with access and using those credentials is possible, but it's definitely not ideal..

**2.** So I looked at the [OAuth2 Secret/Key](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) method in the API docs. But it doesn't work. If I curl the org repo url with my credentials as params in the url:

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos?private&client_id=<ID>&client_secret=<SECRET>"
```

Only the public repos show up. This may be a problem with how I'm passing params (passing "?private=true" should theoretically then return an empty list, but the list is identical and all public repos), but I'm following the docs.

**3.** So I got frustrated and took a look at [these docs](http://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/) for getting a OAuth token, but I'm confused about how to alter it so that there's no user interface -- ie, so that my app has automatic access to the Github Orgs of which I am a member, without users of it having to do anything in particular.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with attempt 2, or how to get attempt 3 working automatically? I'm pretty stumped.

**EDIT** I think my client_id/secret are wrong, cause even when I use Octokit, it can't access the protected repos. Am I understanding this wrong? As me, I created an "Application" on Github for my Rails app, and I'm trying to use those credentials to access the org's private repos (to which I am a contributor) using the API.

Comment: Recommend https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb

Comment: Cool gem! But I seem to still be having problems authenticating with it. If I pass in my credentials as the new client's client_id and client_secret, I still don't get access to the org's private repos. Is this a problem with my client_id and client_secret credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this problem, here's the solution I found.

Apparently the client credentials I had weren't working. I think I didn't quite understand what they're for. The easiest way I could get this to work (ie, get permission for my rails app to access a private repo of which I was a member) was to use the username:password method (1, above).

So that my personal github credentials wouldn't be available to everyone using the app, I created a new dummy github account with access that serves exclusively as an api credentializer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm precisely facing the same issue. I find it surprising there is no more proper way though… Even more now since there is 2-step auth D:

Answer (score 0):

I am using Octokit with C# and encountered the same issue. After some investigation I found out it was a problem with my token permissions.

Token have scopes (https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) so to access private repositories you need 'repo' instead of 'public_repo' which I think was default.

This can be easily changed from Settings > [Personal Access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) > edit