# Github create token with 2 factor authentication

Tags: api, curl, github, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get a authorize a user and get a token back. The user has 2 factor authentication on.

This is the code I am tring to use. It will not accept the code I get via SMS. This works if the user does not have 2fa enabled.

```
curl -i -u $user -H "X-GitHub-OTP: $code" \
     -d '{"scopes": [ "repo" ], "note": "program"}' \
     https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication
http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually works. I was having problems with the SMS codes expiring.